# Enum Property Default Title if nothing is selected

Tags: python, properties

I would like to have a default text on my dynamic enum property. For example "Choose something".
How can I do this?

When I specify a text in the panel, the text always stays there. But I would like to have "Choose something" only if nothing has been selected yet.

This is what my dynamic enum looks like:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import EnumProperty
                       
                       
def Enum_Items(self,context):
    
    EnumItems = [('1','Fluegel',''),('2','Nägel',''),('3','Mönch','')]
    
    return EnumItems

def Dynamic_Enum(context):
    
    Index = 0
    
#    Dynamic_Enum.enum_items = [((line.body, line.body, "")) for line in bpy.data.texts['Text'].lines]
    
    Dynamic_Enum.enum_items = []
    for line in bpy.data.texts['Text'].lines:
        Dynamic_Enum.enum_items.append((line.body, line.body,""))
    
#Dynamic_Enum.enum_items = [] 
    

class MyProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    
    my_enum : EnumProperty(
        name = "Enumarator / Dropdown",
        description = "sample text",
        items = Enum_Items)
        
    Dynamic_Enum : EnumProperty(
        name = "Enumarator_2 / Dropdown",
        description = "dynamic items",
        items = lambda self, context: Dynamic_Enum.enum_items,
        )

class ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_idname = "ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Test Tab"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        mytool = context.scene.my_tool
        Dynamic_Enum(context) # Update enum items before drawing them
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_enum",text="static")
        layout.prop(mytool, "Dynamic_Enum", text= "dynamic")

    

classes = [MyProperties, ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel]
 
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
#Props zugänglich machen
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyProperties)
        
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
#Props zugänglich machen
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
        
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I think you're having an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here and you're trying to push the EnumProperty to its limits. If you can click on an enum item, but you remove it when the enum item is picked, you will have picked the n-1 item, so it can't be done I'm afraid. But it's an interesting challenge so here's my take on it : https://gist.github.com/Gorgious56/4864c2c4eed1110b33916015faadf805

Comment: This looks good, thank you very much!